# Указатели Си. Декодирование данных

Tags: c, указатели, urlencode

Суть в том, что длина декодированных данных меньше, что url-кодированных. В итоге мы помещаем декодированные данные в ту же строку. Как тогда заменяются все символы в начальной строке?

```
  // Функция URL-декодирования.
    // Функция преобразует строку данных st в нормальное представление.
    // Результат помещается в ту же строку, что была передана в параметрах.
    void url_decode(char *st) {
      char *p = st;  // указывает на текущий символ строки
      char hex[3]; // временный буфер для хранения %XX
      int code;    // преобразованный код
      // запускаем цикл, пока не кончится строка (т. е. пока 
      // не появится символ с кодом 0, см. ниже)
      do {
        // Если это %-код ...
        if(*st == '%') { // тогда копируем его во временный буфер
          hex[0] = *(++st);
          hex[1] = *(++st);
          hex[2] = 0;
          // переводим его в число
          sscanf(hex, "%X", &code);
          // и записываем обратно в строку
          *p++ = (char)code;
          // указатель p всегда отмечает то место в строке, в которое
          // будет помещен очередной декодированный символ
        }
        // иначе, если это "+", то заменяем его на " "
        else if(*st == '+') *p++ = ' ';
        // а если ни то, ни другое — оставляем, как есть
        else *p++ = *st;
      } while(*st++ != 0); // пока не найдем нулевой код
    }
```

Comment: Что имеется в виду под фразой «заменяются все символы в начальной строке»? Результат отличается от ожидаемого или как? Вопрос непонятен

Comment: *`"Как тогда заменяются все символы в начальной строке? "`* -- суть вопроса не ясна. Именно так, как написано в коде они и замещаются. По мере их анализа поверх них пишутся декодированные.  Если я не ответил на ваш вопрос, попробуйте сформулировать его по другому (или добавьте информации)

Comment: Мы передаем в функцию строку, в которой все данные url - закодированные. Задача  - декодировать все символы в строке и поместить в эту же строку результат. Например, %E2 функция должна заменить на букву в и так всю строку. Мне непонятно, как изначальные 3 байта мы заменим на 1 символ.

Comment: `sscanf(hex, "%X", &code); *p++ = (char)code;` -- вот запись одного байта, а указатель `st` сдвинули на 3

Comment: Функция `sscanf` декодирует строку `hex`, имеющую форму шестнадцатеричного числа, в число и кладёт его в `code`, затем этот `code` записывается на положенное место в исходной строке. `p++` сдвигает указатель для записи на один байт вперёд, а `++st`, `++st` и `st++` в сумме сдвигают указатель для чтения на три байта вперёд. На каком этапе что-то непонятно?

Comment: Непонятно куда делись два байта. Ведь мы с помощью временного буфера hex заменили все 3 байта на число, но ведь два символа url-кодированной строки так и остались в начальной строке, мы ведь их не заменили. Просто поместили уже декодированный символ в самое начало строки, но он ведь не занимает 3 байта.

Comment: Оставшиеся два байта были пропущены с помощью `++st` и `++st`

Comment: А указатель `p` был сдвинут не на три байта, а всего лишь на один, поэтому эти два пропущенных байта в дальнейшем перезатираются новыми символами

Comment: Получается, что в самом конце строки так и останутся url - кодированные символы?

Comment: Не совсем. Символ процента будет заменён декодированным символом в строке `*p++ = (char)code;`, первая половина кода будет заменена нулевым байтом в строке `*p++ = *st` когда цикл дойдёт до конца строки, а вот вторая половина кода действительно останется нетронутой. Но так как она стоит после нулевого байта, обозначающего конец строки, это уже не имеет никакого значения

Comment: И кстати этот код небезопасен, так допускает пропуск нулевого байта перед sscanf (если процент является последним или предпоследним символом в строке) и последующий выход за пределы буфера с непредсказуемыми последствиями. Если злоумышленник сможет разместить какую-нибудь ещё строку по соседству, то он, вероятно, получит возможность внедрения и выполнения произвольного кода, если программа не рухнет от ошибки сегментирования.

Comment: Все, понял. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Мирон, кстати, наверное неплохо было бы диагностировать возможную ошибку, связанную с содержимым  `hex[]` и как-то сообщить о ней вызывающему коду